# Firestore rules - How to allow create but not update?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here's what I’ve written;

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /reservedUsernames/{username} {
      allow update: if false;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I already added a document with ID `sam` and a field `userId` = `122`. If I run an update on that document, see how below, it succeeds! How can I allow creations but no updates?

```
db.collection("reservedUsernames")
  .document(searchableUsername)
  .setData(["userId": userId])
```

Comment: We can't see that the name of the actual document exactly matches the value of the variable `searchableUsername`.  Also, "if false" doesn't really do anything special compared to leaving out the update line altogether.  The default is to disallow everything other than what is explicitly allowed.

Comment: The `searchableUsername` matches the document's id and it updates it. That's what I want to prevent... the updates. I want to disallow changes to documents.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the line you added to reject updates doesn't actually do anything - all access is rejected until some rule allows it.  It's a pure allowlist, not an denylist.  You can certainly be explicit about it, but it's non-functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it by using Security Rules:

```
rules_version = '2'

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /reservedUsernames/{documentId} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null && existingData(resource) == null
    }

    function incomingData(request) {
      return request == null || request.resource == null || request.resource.data == null ? null : request.resource.data
    }

    function existingData(resource) {
      return resource == null ? null : resource.data
    }
  }
}
```

This way I check if I'm updating an existing document and it passes only if I'm not!

Answer (score 1):

When using:

```
.setData(["userId": userId])
```

It means that you're [setting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#setdata_:) the data, and **not** [updating](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#updatedata_:) it. The following rule:

```
allow update: if false;
```

Indeed rejects all update operations but as @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, having it in your rules it's the exact same thing as not having it at all, because by default the rules are set to false.

Comment: Ok, got that! So how can I actually create a document with id, and not set it?

Comment: There is no way you can create a document, without using `set`. The `update` function work, as the name, says, only for existing data, right?

Comment: Right, so if `set` creates AND updates a document if it already exists, what can I do to prevent the updates?

Comment: When you call `set` for the first time, it adds the data. When you call it a second time on the exact same reference, it overwrites the data. That's **not** an update.

Comment: You’re right, I worded it incorrectly. How can I prevent all overrides?

Comment: If you want to write the data only once then you have to check if the document exists. If it doesn't exist, create the document, otherwise, take no action. Is it clear now?

Comment: Ok! I hoped I could do it without querying, but I guess I can't. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome, Sotiris.

Comment: So can I help you with other information?

Comment: I don’t think I need anything else. Thanks again!